# How would I save models generated in a loop to a list?

Tags: r, list, loops

I'm trying to make a list called "`Models`" that contains a list of 10 models.

Here's the code I am using. (Typed into the interpreter)

```
 models=list()
 for (degree in 1:10){
 myFormula=as.formula(paste0("nox ~ poly(dis, ",degree,")"))
 myModel=lm(myFormula,data=Boston)
 print(deviance(myModel))
 models=append(models,myModel)
}
```

For some reason, the length of models after this is 120 instead of 10. I'm used to python, where the append statement would just add one object and they'd all be distinct.

I don't know why this isn't working that way or how to do it correctly.

Comment: Try `models[[degree]] <- myModel` instead of `models=append(models,myModel)`

Comment: @AllanCameron that seems to work, but why does it? Why am I allowed to add something to an index that doesn't yet exist?

Comment: You're not, you're creating the index and writing to it in the same operation.  The reason why `append` doesn't work here is that an `lm` object is actually a list "under the hood", and when you append it to another list, it loses its attributes and becomes a list with 12 or 13 members that are added on to the other list. That's why your result was a list with 120 members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `lapply`

```
models = lapply(1:10, function(degree) {
  myFormula=as.formula(paste0("nox ~ poly(dis, ",degree,")"))
  lm(myFormula,data=Boston)
})
```

If you want the deviance of each model, you can do:

```
lapply(models, deviance)
```

Or equivalently

```
lapply(models, function(mod) deviance(mod))
```

You could also have returned both the model and its deviance (as a list) in the original loop like this; note that this returns a list of lists. The result, `models` is 10 elements long (one for each `degree`), and each element itself is a list (this one is a named list), with the first element being the model, and the second element being the variance

```
models = lapply(1:10, function(degree) {
  myFormula=as.formula(paste0("nox ~ poly(dis, ",degree,")"))
  mod = lm(myFormula,data=Boston)
  list(model = mod, deviance=deviance(mod))
})
```

Comment: This seems to work, would be nice to have some more details about lapply, and if there's a way to get the variance out

Comment: `lapply` returns a list of the same length as its first input argument, in this case the sequence 1:10. The second argument is a function, which will be apply to each element of the first input, and the result of that function will be the value of that element of the resulting list.   I noticed in your post that you printed the deviance;  Perhaps a better way might be save it. I've added a couple of options for you to save the deviance

Answer (score 0):

We can add elements to list using `c`,

```
 models=list()

 for (degree in 1:10){

 myFormula=as.formula(paste0("nox ~ poly(dis, ",degree,")"))

 myModel=lm(myFormula,data=Boston)

 print(deviance(myModel))

 models= c(models,list(myModel))

}
```

Comment: Still gives a length of 120, which doesn't seem right

Comment: `mymodel` is a list thus just using `c` gave you 120 length. Modified the answer maybe this will work.